# Echo client with over 65% packet losses

Tags: c, networking, udp

I'm just wondering why my UDP [server](http://github.com/konr/Licio/blob/master/03/server.c)/[client](http://github.com/konr/Licio/blob/master/03/client.c) pair is getting 65% packet loss. It's just an echo service that sends (the client) an empty packet when it reaches EOF, and the server resets itself when he gets that empty packet.

Not really homework, just frustrated because I can't get it right :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at udp buffer overflows?
Here is information on [packet loss myths](http://www.29west.com/docs/THPM/packet-loss-myths.html) how to detect [UDP packet loss rates](http://www.29west.com/docs/THPM/udp-buffer-sizing.html#DETECTING-UDP-LOSS) on several platforms. And last but by no means least how to [mess with (err... I mean change) the kernel udp buffer sizes](http://www.29west.com/docs/THPM/udp-buffer-sizing.html) for a few unix platforms (caution is advisable).

Answer (score 2):

There's no promise that UDP packets will ever be delivered.  On congested networks, UDP packets may just be dropped in transit.

There are also routers that are configured to just drop empty UDP packets.  See this [random example](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=693378) of someone wanting this.